# unlist file from PHP glob function

Tags: php, glob

I have 25 files under 1 folder, which I have included using glob in PHP

```
    foreach (glob(PATH."*.php") as $filename) {
    require_once $filename; 
    }
```

I want to exclude 1 file from this list while testing, how do I achieve that ?
The `preg_grep` would be difficult to change again and again. What I am trying to achieve is not to mess with the current things and add new files in the folder. I want to exclude the newly added file until it is error free and doesn't harm the current setup.

Comment: If you know the name of the file you don't want to include, just add a simple `if` before including it... unless I'm missing something?

Comment: What file needs to be excluded and why? You may be able to exclude it by adjusting the glob pattern.

Comment: Honestly, I can guarantee there's a better way to do this. Not only is this inclusion method dangerous, it's slow. You should explicitly include the files you know you will need on every request, and use an auto loader for files after that

Comment: Yes, I agree with using autoloader. But I have to include all the files from this particular folder, as it is important core files and would be needed in other pages where I `include` them.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Specifically exclude the file:

```
foreach (glob(PATH."*.php") as $filename) {
  if ($filename!='excluded_file.php') {
    require_once $filename;
  }
}
```

If you want to get really sexy:

```
$exclude_files=array('exclude1.php','exclude2.php');

foreach (glob(PATH."*.php") as $filename) {
  if (!in_array($filename,$exclude_files)) { require_once $filename; }
}
```

Or just temporarily remove the problem file from the directory.